# looping through two database tables

Tags: php, mysql

in my database, i have tables like `post` and `user`. i want to be able to show who posted which posts.

i used the following `foreach` loop. what i want to achieve is to have another `foreach` loop so that i can loop for the `user` or is there another way to do this?

`post table`

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
| post_id      | user_id            | title             | time             |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
| 1            | 2                  | Good service      | 12:00PM          |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
| 2            | 3                  | Thank you         | 2:46PM           |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
| 3            | 1                  | Enquiry           | 11:28AM          |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
```

`user table`

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| user_id      | name               | email             |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1            | Jane               | jane@gmail.com    |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 2            | Ben                | ben@gmail.com     |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 3            | John               | john@gmail.com    |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+


$sql = "SELECT * FROM post p inner join user u ";
                    $sql .= "ON p.user_id = u.user_id ";
                    $sql .= "LIMIT {$per_page} ";
                    $sql .= "OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
                    $posts = post::find_by_sql($sql);

foreach ($posts as $post) {    
  echo "<div class='panel-body'>" .
  "<div class='post'>" .
  "<h3>";
  echo $post->title;
  echo "</h3>";
  echo "<p><span class='name'>" . $post->name . " - " . $post->time . "</span>";
  //the rest are the continuation of the html and php codes for looping `$post`
}
```

`name` is taken from the `user` table while the other variables are from the `post` table.

error: `Notice: Undefined property: post::$name`

although i do not have `name` in the `post` table, i have joined the two tables together?

Comment: you don't select anything from the user table. `* FROM post p, * from user u ...`

Comment: What are the column names  in both tables?

Comment: For simplicity: `SELECT p.*, u.* FROM...`

Comment: column names are added @Anonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post p inner join user u ";
  $sql .= "ON p.user_id = u.user_id ";
  $sql .= "LIMIT {$per_page} ";
  $sql .= "OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
  $posts = post::find_by_sql($sql);

foreach ($posts as $jp) {
  $user = User::find_by_id($jp->user_id);   //add this
  echo "<div class='panel-body'>" .
  "<div class='post'>" .
  "<h3>";
  echo $jp->title;
  echo "</h3>";
  echo "<p><span class='name'>" . $user->name . " - " . $jp->time . "</span>";
  //the rest are the continuation of the html and php codes for looping `$post`
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You would need to to get your value from 'u.name' column in the result set not from 'name' and similar.  This is because you are using SELECT *

So the values would be at $post['u.name'] and similar.

You really should move away from * selects and select only the columns you need possibly including column aliases to make result lookup easier.

Comment: If the columns don't conflict, they will all be selected with * and have their regular column name. There's nothing that would turn the array key into `'u.name'`. It's not even an array in the example, it's an object.